# Way to Log Function Calls in SWF at Runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way (tool, library, etc.) to log all the actionscript function calls at runtime in a SWF created from Flash Professional? I often inherit projects, and want to more easily analyze and understand their operation. Profiling be nice too.

Comment: not yet... http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-sneak-peeks/max-2011-sneak-peek-monocle/

Answer (score 0):

Logging *all* calls will probably not help much, because if there are many "small" items involved (i.e. cells in a list, nodes in a tree, particles in a particle engine, enemies in a game, etc. etc.) the log files will clutter up with repetition and soon grow to a size where the sheer amount of information will make learning about the functionality a slow, tedious and painful task.

It is more useful to use a profiler to manage dependencies, memory etc., and use a debugger to step through the code, and/or set breakpoints at interesting points and navigate deeper into the architecture from there.

[FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) has a great [profiler](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Intro_To_Profiling_Applications) and [debugger](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Using_FDT%27s_Debugger).  And as a free tool, [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Show method entry** and **Show method exit** in [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger).  It also offers some profiling.  You can also track object creation and destruction, and memory usage.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I wrote this app*

Comment: This looks really promising... Too bad it doesn't work with SWFs inside an HTML page - you can't debug much enterprise code without session cookies. :(